# Opening .xlsx created in MsExcel 07 with apache poi causes POIXMLException

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, xlsx

i am using XSSFWorkbook from Apache Poi "3.10-FINAL" in order to read .xlsx files.

Working on .xslx produced by Ms Office '03 and '13 everything works fine and i can open the .xlsx like this:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xlsxInByteArray);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
```

With some file produced in *MS Office '07 version : 12.0.6683 SP3 MSO (12.0.6683.5000)* the constructor of XSSFWorkbook raises the exception :

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException:
Package should contain a content type part
```

Also tried another way using WorkbookFactory

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xlsxInByteArray);
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
```

to open this file and i get another exception :

```
Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
```

Any clues?

I can provide you some information about the file concerned :
This is the Apache Tika's analysis =

> Application-Name: Microsoft Excel Application-Version: 12.0000
>
> Author: xxx
>
> Content-Length: 129536
>
> Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
>
> Creation-Date: 2014-05-15T13:24:43Z
>
> Last-Author: xxx
>
> Last-Modified: 2016-12-16T14:58:57Z
>
> Last-Save-Date: 2016-12-16T14:58:57Z
>
> X-Parsed-By: org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser
>
> X-Parsed-By: org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser
>
> X-TIKA:digest:MD5: 9b37037534cdaaedf7eb799208aa71e3
>
> X-TIKA:digest:SHA256: 514e82b77ac6ba4c6da37525ca4aec7f7ffc6d5377823d9ae3410e4c6b4f2523
>
> creator: xxx
>
> date: 2016-12-16T14:58:57Z
>
> dc:creator: xxx
>   dc:publisher: xxx
>   dcterms:created: 2014-05-15T13:24:43Z
>   dcterms:modified: 2016-12-16T14:58:57Z
>
> extended-properties:AppVersion: 12.0000
>   extended-properties:Application: Microsoft Excel
>   extended-properties:Company: xxx
>
> meta:author: xxx
>   meta:creation-date: 2014-05-15T13:24:43Z
>   meta:last-author:xxx
>   meta:save-date: 2016-12-16T14:58:57Z
>
> modified: 2016-12-16T14:58:57Z
>   protected: true
>   publisher: xxx
>   resourceName: File from Office 07.xlsx

And if i open the file like an archive i get this :
[file opened in 7zip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS7Nc.png)

Note:
If i open this file in MS Excel '13 i can read with no warning or problems the file.

Comment: The screenshot tells me 7zip knows about the OLE format, which is not a .zip file, and that you deal with an encrypted/password protected file. So I would try a current version of POI (e.g 3.16 beta1) and check the [encryption pages](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html)

Comment: ... and if this doesn't work, you can send me the file to my apache mail and I'll have a look

Comment: i've also tried to open the file with a poifsFilesystem and a decryptor like read http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html and still raise an exception like this 
Invalid header signature; read 0x0000000000060009, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document

Comment: i will try with the newer apache POI 3-16 beta1